# Closest point based on angle and distance

Tags: angle, euclidean-distance

I have a set of points **P1,P2** and **P3**. I am trying to find the closest point to P1 by using the angle and distance informations. As you can See the closest point to **P1** is **P2** base on the **Y** coordinates but the angle deviation is greater than the angle with **P3**. The point that i should chose as solution should be **P3**. Is there a formula or a similar problem that was solved?

Thank you.

[image: Closest Point]

Comment: Perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: Why don't you calculate the distances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then the distance between two points is `Y-distance / cos(\theta)`

Comment: So Suppose the angle between < P1,P2 = 35° and <P1P3 = 0°.
and the distance between P1,P2 = 10, and P1,P3 = 13
So 13/cos(0) = 13 and 13/cos(35) = 15.87. 

Well yes this might work. yes yes